# Loading a pre-trained spaCy transformer with Hugging Face fails because of missing config.json

Tags: nlp, spacy, huggingface-transformers, spacy-transformers

I am trying to get into NLP with Hugging Face, Presidio and spaCy. Following the [Presidio tutorial](https://microsoft.github.io/presidio/analyzer/nlp_engines/transformers/), I tried downloading a pre-trained spaCy transformer named `de_dep_news_trf` like this:

```
import transformers
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification

transformers_model = 'spacy/de_dep_news_trf'

snapshot_download(repo_id=transformers_model)

# Instantiate to make sure it's downloaded during installation and not runtime
AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(transformers_model)
AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(transformers_model)
```

The line `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(transformers_model)` fails:

```
OSError: spacy/de_dep_news_trf does not appear to have a file named config.json. Checkout 'https://huggingface.co/spacy/de_dep_news_trf/main' for available files.
```

While https://huggingface.co/spacy/de_dep_news_trf/main leads to a 404, there is indeed no config.json at https://huggingface.co/spacy/de_dep_news_trf/tree/main. There is a config.cfg. Can I use that somehow? If not, how can I use this transformer?

Comment: So this is a bug that's been reported in spacy that saving a spacy model apparently does not save all of the standard transformer requirements.  I am working on this problem as well but it looks like the easiest way would be to use spacy.cli from a python script.  Unfortunately it seems that the spacy wrapper breaks backwards compatibility.